# IE11 doesn't work well with Blob constructor & javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, blob

I've been using Blob of HTML5 to consolidate a bunch of data including files and strings. Since the files and strings to be sent are not pre-specified in program, and I need to pack all data in a JS file and send them immediately, so I use Array of javascript to collect available data, then make this array as a parameter of Blob constructor. It works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but throws a javascript error when using IE11.

> Unhandled exception at line 161, column 9 in @#$%.js
>   0x800a139e - JavaScript Runtime Error: InvalidStateError

My code is as follows:

```
var blobPackage_array = [];
if(userType != null)
    blobPackage_array.push(userType);

if(userInfo != null)
    blobPackage_array.push(userInfo);

for (var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
    blobPackage_array.push(fileList[i]);
}  

var blobPackage = new Blob(blobPackage_array); //throw javascript runtime error
```

I previously suspected that IE doesn't support Blob, so I tested this:

```
var blobPackage = new Blob(["test", fileList[0]]);
```

It worked fine, no error. My last guess is that IE doesn't recognise `blobPackage_array` as a valid parameter of Blob constructor. But Blob doesn't have a append method, meanwhile I can not know how many files that need to be appended, which means I can not construct a Blob once and for all. 
Anyone ever encounter this? anything I can use to bypass this? I'd appreciate any suggestion.

---

Update! For some reason, I can not use `FormData` instead, It has to be blob...
anybody can help me on this?

---

Update again! Thanks to your kind reply, there are some progress. I checked MSDN, Blob's constructor should be like this: `var blobObject = new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], { type: 'image/png' });`. I tried to construct a `Uint8Array` with `blobPackage_array` by this `var uint8array = new Uint8Array(blobPackage_array);`. I find that data is lost while this transformation. But in fact, `var blobPackage = new Blob([uint8array]);` can work, without errors. Thus I just need to fix the transformation problem.

Comment: It looks like you should be using `formData` instead, if you're sending strings and files to the serverside ?

Comment: @adeneo Oh, I chose `Blob` over `FormData`, and I don't remember why I made this choice, maybe I need to reconsider FormData, thank you for your advice.

Comment: @adeneo I am sending data to serverside.

Comment: MSDN says, that the Blob constructor takes an `Uint8Array`

Comment: @meskobalazs  Thank you for your reply. I checked MSDN, it is as you said. I tried to construct a `Uint8Array` with `blobPackage_array` by this `var uint8array = new Uint8Array(blobPackage_array);`. I find that data is lost while this transformation. But in fact, `var blobPackage = new Blob([uint8array]);` can work, without errors. Thus I just need to fix the transformation problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. I'm such an idiot..IE do not recognize my original `blobPackage_array` as a valid parameter because of those variables I append:

```
if(userType != null)
    blobPackage_array.push(userType);
```

I just need to validate `userType` by this:

```
if(userType != null)
    blobPackage_array.push(new String(userType));
```

So, don't bother to transform all data to UInt8Array type...